# Variables $_POST vacias

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Cuando intento hacer una consulta al momento de mandar las variables por medio de ajax el PHP las recibe vacías, imprimo las variables que tiene el ajax y aparecen correctamente, también se envían pero al momento de querer utilizarlas en el código php es ahí donde aparecen vacías

Javascript:

```
function Registro(){
  var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
  var domicilio = $("#domicilio").val();
  var colonia = $("#colonia").val();
  var cp = $("#cp").val();
  var ciudad = $("#ciudad").val();
  var estado = $("#estado").val();
  var telefono = $("#telefono").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if ( 
    nombre != ' ' && domicilio != ' ' && colonia != ' ' && cp != ' ' &&
    ciudad != ' ' && estado != ' ' && telefono != ' ' && email != ' '
  ) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'html',
      url: "PHP/cclient.php",
      data: {"nombre": nombre," domicilio": domicilio," colonia": colonia,"
      cp":cp," ciudad": ciudad
      ," estado":estado," telefono": telefono," email": email},
      success: function(resp){
        Limpiar();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

---

PHP

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

$nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
$domicilio = $_POST['domicilio'];
$colonia = $_POST['colonia'];
$cp = $_POST['cp'];
$ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes(
    IdCliente, nombre, domicilio, colonia,
    cp, ciudad, estado, celular, email
  ) VALUES (
    NULL, '$nombre', '$domicilio', '$colonia',
    '$cp', '$ciudad', '$estado', '$estado', '$telefono', '$email'
  );
";

$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo $sql;
?>
```

Comment: Prueba $_POST["variable"] en lugar de $HTTP_POST_VARS['variable']

Comment: usar `HTTP_POST_VARS` es algo viejo, usa $_POST , lo otro que veo es que en en la parte de javascript en el jquery que hace el envio de los datos `data: "nombre="+nombre+"&domicilio="+domicilio+"&colonia="+colonia+"&cp="+cp+"&ciudad="+ciudad
    +"&estado="+estado+"&telefono="+telefono+"&email="+email` deberia ser de esta manera:  `{"nombre": nombre, "domicilio": domicilio} `(aqui solo puse algunos para no hacer mas grande mi respuesta xD

Comment: tambien puedes ver el contenido de lo que recibes haciendo un `var_dump` o `print_r` a `$_POST` :D

Comment: listo hice el cambio y sigue sin nada, hago el echo de la query que quiero realizar y me aparece esto 
INSERT INTO clientes(IdCliente,nombre,domicilio,colonia,cp,ciudad,estado,celular,email) VALUES (NULL,'','','','','','','','','');

Comment: Pon el código como lo tienes ahora para revisarlo, puedes pulsar en [edit] para agregarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenés que enviar la petición http por medio de AJAX, como un objeto válido de Javascrpt es decir dentro de llaves {}

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="form" type>

        <input type="text" placeholder="nombre" name="nombre" id="nombre">
        <input type="text" placeholder="domicilio" name="domicilio" id="domicilio">
        <input type="text" placeholder="colonia" name="colonia" id="colonia">
        <input type="text" placeholder="cp" name="cp" id="cp">
        <input type="text" placeholder="ciudad" name="ciudad" id="ciudad">
        <input type="text" placeholder="estado" name="estado" id="estado">
        <input type="text" placeholder="telefono" name="telefono" id="telefono">
        <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email">
        <button type="button" onclick="registrar()">Enviar</button>
    </form>

</body>
<script>
    function registrar() {
        // Captura de información por medio de Jquery
        // Si quisieras realizarlo por javascript // document.getElementById('nombre')
        let nombre = $("#nombre").val()
        let domicilio = $("#domicilio").val()
        let colonia = $("#colonia").val()
        let cp = $("#cp").val()
        let ciudad = $("#ciudad").val()
        let estado = $("#estado").val()
        let telefono = $("#telefono").val()
        let email = $("#email").val()

        // Petición AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: "cclient.php",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            // la petición Ajax, en el método post espera  los valores en un objeto Javascript.
            data: { nombre: nombre, domicilio: domicilio, colonia: colonia, cp: cp, ciudad: ciudad, estado: estado, telefono: telefono, email: email },
            success: function (respuesta) {
                // Limpiar(); // Función limpiar
            }
        });
    }

</script>

</html>
```

Al ser una petición por POST, no debés hacer como si los vas a concatener con el **&** sino separarlo por coma para dar continuidad al objeto Javascript, la concatenación es para las peticiones GET (**"nombre="+nombre+"&domicilio**)

Tienes que crear una variable para nombre que capture tu valor del input
Ejemplo:

```
let nombre = $("miCampoHTML").val()
let otroCampo = $("miOtrocampoHTML").val()

{nombre: nombre, otroCampo: otroCampo}
```

Por otro lado recupera el valor de las variables con $_POST["domicilio"];

```
<?php

// Obtener información enviada desde Javascript
$nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
$domicilio = $_POST['domicilio'];
$colonia = $_POST['colonia'];
$cp = $_POST['cp'];
$ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes(IdCliente,nombre,domicilio,colonia,cp,ciudad,estado,celular,email) VALUES 
(NULL,'$nombre','$domicilio','$colonia','$cp','$ciudad','$estado','$estado','$telefono','$email');";

// Validar que los valores se muestren correctamente
echo $sql;
die();
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
```

**Recomendaciones:**

• Utilizá visual studio code, con ALT+ SHIFT+F tabulás tu código.

• Si estás iniciando en programación, aprovechando que estás iniciando te recomiendo que utilices nuevas tecnologías (Angular, React, Vue).

• Apoyate, de las opciones de desarrollador del navegador (F12) en la sección de network, podrías visualizar tus peticiones HTTP y verificar que información le estás enviando.

Comment: Acabo de utilizar esas opciones y sigue sin mostrarme nada, se supone que no soy nuevo pero es muy extraño este problema ya que esto sucede solo en una seccion del sistema al agregar clientes, con otras partes del sistema me funciona bien el paso de variables a PHP

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\JamesGarage\PHP\cclient.php on line 11
INSERT INTO clientes(IdCliente,nombre,domicilio,colonia,cp,ciudad,estado,celular,email) VALUES (NULL,'','','','','','','','','');

Comment: Lamento el inconveniente, he modificado la respuesta, ya que al ser un objeto de javascript, debes definir tus propiedades y luego valor de esta manera propiedad: "mivalor", prueba realizar un echo $_POST["domicilio"]; die(); para visualizar, si en efecto lleva el valor que le envías desde ajax.

Comment: Siempre apoyate de las opciones del navegador, en la sección de network.

Comment: Este es el resultado que obtengo del echo de la query que intento realizar y este es el resultado 
INSERT INTO clientes(IdCliente,nombre,domicilio,colonia,cp,ciudad,estado,celular,email) VALUES (NULL,'','','','','','','','','');

Comment: He modificado la solución, espero te sirva ;)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo siguiente, elimina las comillas del "data" para que este quede de la siguiente forma:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'html',
      url: "PHP/cclient.php",
      data: {nombre:nombre,
            domicilio: domicilio,
            colonia:colonia,
            cp:cp, 
            ciudad:ciudad, 
            estado:estado, 
            telefono:telefono,
            email:email
      },
      success: function(resp){
        Limpiar();
      }
});
```

Utiliza las herramientas del navegador para ver si realmente estas mandado los valores a tu archivo cclient.php y si no lo estas mandado pues el problema esta en tus "selectors" de Jquery donde obtienes los valores de las variables $("#id").val();